# SQL Server : query apply in where clause with IS NOT Null on Column that contains Json Object taking more time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in a SQL Server database that columns contain JSON object and that column I iterating through where clause condition with IN NOT NULL, by using openJson JSON_Value and JSON_Query function.The query is running successfully but it taking more time to response output.only in 4 rows taking 7sec.
Then what about if table having 1000 of rows.

Table looks lie this:

[image]

[image]

Here is the query on table that's I'm using:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) 
    [Id], JSON_Value(objectJson,'$.Details.Name.Value') AS objectValue 
FROM  
    [geodb].[dbo].[userDetails]
WHERE
    JSON_QUERY(jsonData,'$."1bf1548c-3703-88de-108e-bf7c4578c912"') IS NOT NULL
```

So, how to optimize above query so that it takes less time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest altering the table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Table
ADD Value AS JSON_VALUE(JsonData, '$.Details.Name.Value');
```

then creating a non clustered index on value column

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ParsedValue ON dbo.Table (Value)
```

This will speed up the query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But I'm not supposed to Alter the existing table.Could you help me with an alternative way?

Comment: I applied insert trigger on the table and flatten Json and then applied non-clustered index on the newly created table.